# How to store muliple value rows per key in java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, key-value-coding

i have a Key ABC.

This Key can have below values (number of rows in not known)

A,B,C,D,E,123

A,C,V,X,S,12

A,C,D,S,A,124

so on

there will multiple keys(<10,000) and every key will have multiple value row.

please help how i can implement it in java ,(based on matching key and starting  5 values of value i would want to get value of 6th i.e 123,12,124).

i need to create above hashmap using a file with below content :-

ABC,A,B,C,D,E,123

ABC,A,C,V,X,S,12

ABC,A,C,D,S,A,124

Comment: Use a `Map<String,List<YourCustomObject>>` where `YourCustomObject` is a class that contains the data for each row.

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps can take in any data structure. So if you use a List structure you can continue adding to the value. You can initialise the HashMap like this: `Map<String, List<String> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>();` The type that the List takes in could also be an object if you are making a class to take in the rows.